# Not able to fetch configuration from git using username and password [Spring Cloud Config ]

Tags: spring, git, spring-cloud

I am using Spring Cloud Config so I set below mentioned configuration in my bootstrap.yml of Config Server.

```
---
spring:
  application:
    name: sample-config
  cloud:
    config:
       server:
         git:
           uri: https://github.com/ragnar-lothbrok/fileUpload/
           username: xxx
           password: yyy

eureka:
  instance:
    nonSecurePort: ${server.port:8888}
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://${eureka.host:localhost}:${eureka.port:8761}/eureka/
```

But when I am starting Client it is throwing exception that properties not found which I am using in Controllers.

Answer (score 1):

There are two h's in this line:

```
uri: hhttps://github.com/ragnar-lothbrok/fileUpload/
```

It should read:

```
uri: https://github.com/ragnar-lothbrok/fileUpload/
```